# Custom 'run' like task for for a project

Tags: scala, build, sbt

By default, the run task for my SBT build executes my main class found (automatically) in `src/main/scala/`.

How can I add a new task for a project that behaves just like the run task but finds a main class in `src/util/scala`? The task should run the util main method with `src/main/scala` on the classpath.

I am using SBT 0.12.4 with a full multi project configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following defines a new configuration that compiles sources from `src/util/scala` and defines `util:run` and `util:run-main` to run main classes from the new configuration.  The compiled sources from `src/main/scala` are available on the classpath when compiling and running.

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object MyBuild extends Build
{
   // Define a new configuration named `util`.
   //   Extending `Compile` means the main classpath is available to `util`
   lazy val Util = config("util").extend(Compile)

   // Add the new configuration to the project.
   // Add the new settings.
   lazy val root = Project("root", file(".")).configs(Util).settings( utilSettings : _*)

   // Add the basic source, compilation, and packaging settings
   //   as well as custom run methods.
   lazy val utilSettings = inConfig(Util)( Defaults.configSettings ++ utilRunSettings )

   // Settings that define `run` and `run-main` to use the
   // classpath from the enclosing configuration.
   // (The standard `run` methods use the `Runtime` configuration.
   lazy val utilRunSettings = Seq(
        run <<= Defaults.runTask(fullClasspath, mainClass in run, runner in run),
        runMain <<= Defaults.runMainTask(fullClasspath, runner in run)
   )
}
```

(Was tested on 0.13, but should work on 0.12.)

Comment: This looks great. Time to try it out.

Comment: So far my project build file compiles but `util:run` automatically finds and runs the main class from `src/main/scala`.

Comment: I tested the pasted code and `util:run` runs the main class in `src/util/scala` only.  Perhaps you can verify the snippet works in a standalone project and then post how you integrated it into your build?

Comment: Took me a while to get around to trying this again, but it works nicely. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think sbt will find code that you put in src/util/... it should go in src/main/scala, src/test/scala, etc.  You might want to add utility classes to some kind of "util" package, maybe in src/main/com/example/util, or put them in a sub project or dependent project, but sbt isn't really designed (afaik) to be able to handle arbitrary directory structures.

As far as setting up multiple main methods, sbt run, if it finds multiple main methods in src/main/scala, will let you choose which one to call.

If it's in an external jar you may need to: [Configuring sbt project to include external Main methods in "sbt run"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966717/configuring-sbt-project-to-include-external-main-methods-in-sbt-run)

What I usually do is run `sbt console` and then just import and call the main method directly from there.  For example:

```
sbt console
import com.example.Main
Main(new String[])
```

Since you have sub-projects, if one of your projects is "util," you should be able to use something like `sbt util/run` to run a main method in util/src/main/scala.

You should also be able to use `sbt "util/run-main com.example.MainClass"` if you have multiple main methods in one project.

You might also consider the sbt start-script plugin:
https://github.com/sbt/sbt-start-script

Comment: Per http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Howto/defaultpaths.html, you can add any directory you want to any scope. I *think* I need a new scope, with the `main` and `util` dirs on the source path, and with a 'run' task with a different name. I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: From your link it seems you could configure your project to reference scala sources in myRandomDirectory/main/scala instead of src/main/scala, but I don't think that helps you.  There are many ways to run (multiple) tasks from sbt, and I've used some of the mechanisms listed in my answer. I'm not sure why keeping the main class in a util directory would make a difference.

Comment: I have a main class as well as most of my business logic in `src/main/scala` and I have some utility code in `src/main/util`. The utility code is very much related to the main code so it doesn't seem to warrant its own sub project. The utility code has its own main class and is not test case code, which hangs out in the usual `src/test/scala`.

Comment: Normally you would either add the util code to a project using a multi-project build, or put the util code in a package (for example in src/main/scala/com/example/util/).
afaik scala doesn't mind if directories don't match package names, so perhaps you could have two code dirs: src/main/scala/application and src/main/scala/util. This is an unconventional approach, but should also work.  Sbt can be configured for multiple main methods in a single src/main/scala codebase (as described in the answer), so that isn't a problem. If you must have two completely separate src dirs, use projects.